# Is there a fast algorithm to remove repeated substrings in a string?

Tags: python, string, algorithm

There is a string like it

```
"dxabcabcyyyydxycxcxz"
```

and I want to merge it into

```
"dxabcydxycxz"
```

Other examples:
*"ddxddx" -> "dxdx" , "abbab" -> "abab".*

The rule is that :

```
if (adjacent and same): merge

# Such as 'abc', they are same, so delete one of them
# Although 'dx' is same as 'dx', they are nonadjacent, so do not delete any of them
# If one character has been deleted, don't delete any substring, include it
```

I've done it in Python, but it's slow when applied to a long string.

```
# Original string
mystr = "dxabcabcyyyydxycxcxz"
str_len = len(mystr)
vis = [1] * str_len  # Use a list to mark which char is deleted

# Enumerate the size of substring
for i in range(1,str_len):
    # Enumerate the begin of the substring
    for j in range(0, str_len):
        offset = 2 #the size of sub-str + 1
        current_sub_str = mystr[j:j+i]
        s_begin = j+i*(offset-1)
        s_end = j+(i*offset)
        # Delete all of the same char
        while((j+(i*offset) <= str_len) and current_sub_str == mystr[s_begin:s_end]
              and 0  not in vis[s_begin:s_end] and 0  not in vis[j:j+i]):
            vis[s_begin:s_end] = [0] * (s_end - s_begin)  # If it was deleted, mark it as 0
            offset += 1
            s_begin = j + i * (offset - 1)
            s_end = j + (i * offset)

res = []
for i in range(0,str_len):
    if(vis[i]!=0): res.append(mystr[i])

print "".join(res)
```

Is there any faster way to solve it?

> Update April 29, 2017

Sorry, it seems to be like an XY problem. On the other hand, it maybe not.
There is the content I was coding for a web spider and got many 'tag-path's like those:

```
ul/li/a
ul/li/div/div/div/a/span
ul/li/div/div/div/a/span 
ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
```

As you see, some of the 'tag-path's are identical, so I wanted to collapse them to find out if there is any other 'tag-path's with the same structure.

After collapsing, I get the 'tag-path' like this.

```
ul/li/a
ul/li/div/div/div/a/span
ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
```

This is only my idea and I didn't know whether it is suitable to do this way. (After trying, I chose another way to do it).

However there is an interesting question like an ACM question.

So, I simplify one 'tag-path' to a character and ask for help. Because I didn't do a fast way by myself.
Actually, the question has many corner cases that I don't mind and thank all for helping me to complete it.

Thanks all.

---

Comment: what happen if you find "ddxddx" ? Would you end up with "ddx" or "dxdx" ?

Comment: And how about `abbab` - does it become `ab` or `abab`?

Comment: Sorry, the expectation of 'ddxddx' is 'dxdx' and 'abbab' is 'abab'. I find  some problems in my code.

Comment: If `ddxddx` becomes `dxdx` I don't see how `yyyy` becomes `y` and not `yy`

Comment: Why is `abcabc` contracted to `abc` but not `ddxddx` to `ddx`? Shouldn’t this algorithm look for the longest possible substring that gets repeated?

Comment: @silel, I'm guessing `yyyy` gets replaced as one operation.

Comment: @ poke, Yes. "yyyy" will be  collapsed in the one operation by one character. But "ddxddx" don't, because when we get "dxdx", we won't go on, "d" has been merged.

Comment: @Holloway thank you. I am sorry for I didn't describe the problem clearly

Comment: Just to be sure, should "abadabad" be compressed into "abad"? Could you also explain the point of your algorithm just to make sure this is not some kind of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? Give us some context?

Comment: Another corner case: `abbcabbc`. My opinion, based on your previous examples, is that you want it to become `abcabc`. If so none of the answer (right now) seems to yield the correct output (except yours).

Comment: Sorry, it seems to like a XY problem.On the other hand,it maybe not.
there is the content

I was coding for a web spider and got many 'tag-path's like those
`ul/li/a
ul/li/div/div/div/a/span
ul/li/div/div/div/a/span
ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a`

Comment: I update the question. "abbcabbc "-> "abcabc" and  "abadabad"->"abad"

Comment: I do not quite understand what it is you want to do... I get that you are working on an html document. What does each line/"tag-path" represent? Why do you want to collapse them?

Comment: Your input/output suggest you could have a look at what [`uniq`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq) does (in bash).

Answer (score 17):

Behold the power of regex:

```
>>> import re

>>> re.sub(r"(.+?)\1+", r"\1", "dxabcabcyyyydxycxcxz")
'dxabcydxycxz'

>>> re.sub(r"(.+?)\1+", r"\1", "ddxddx")
'dxdx'

>>> re.sub(r"(.+?)\1+", r"\1", "abbab")
'abab'
```

This looks for a sequence of 1 or more arbitrary characters `(.+?)` (as a non-greedy match, so that it tries shorter sequences first), followed by 1 or more repetitions of the matched sequence `\1+`, and replaces it all with just the matched sequence `\1`.

Comment: Wow, I got  the power of regex.However , As @silel 's case "abbcabbc" -> "abcabc". But this way only get "abbc"

Answer (score 0):

This can be a start:

```
for i in range(len(string)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(string)):
        while string[i:j] == string[j:j + j - i]:
            string = string[:j] + string[j + j - i:]
```

The result on the examples provided:

```
abbab  -> abab
ddxddx -> dxdx
abcabcabc -> abc
dxabcabcyyyydxycxcxz -> dxabcydxycxz
```

Comment: In both cases, the repetitions of 1 character get squeezed. Then you would have to consider the repetitions of blocks of 2 characters, and so on.

Comment: With that rationale you transform `ddxddx` into `ddx`, don't you?

Comment: No. First dd -> d, and dd ->d. So you get dxdx.

Comment: Thank you. In my opinion yyyy -> y,  but in the "ddxddx",the character 'x' break sequence  about "dddd".

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question/series of responses!

Here's an implementation using a generator and string slicing:

```
import math
def dedupe(string, step=1):
    index = 0
    prior = ''
    while index < len(string):
        letter = string[index]
        window = index + step
        comparison = string[index:window]
        if comparison != prior:
            yield letter
            prior += letter
            index += 1
        else:
            index += step
        if len(prior) > (step):
            prior = prior[1:] # remove first character


def collapse(string):
    step = 1
    while step < math.sqrt(len(string)):
        generator = dedupe(string, step=step)
        string = ''.join(generator)
        step +=1
    return string
```

Edit: changed the step search to use the square root of the length to improve search times:

- `%timeit collapse('dxabcabcyyyydxycxcxz')`
  10000 loops, best of 3: 24.7 µs per loop
- `%timeit collapse(randomword(100)`
  1000 loops, best of 3: 384 µs per loop
- `%timeit collapse("a" * 100)`
  10000 loops, best of 3: 27.1 µs per loop
- `%timeit collapse(randomword(50) * 2)`
  1000 loops, best of 3: 382 µs per loop

Comment: I am still waiting for OP's answer on this but your solution on `abadabad` seems to return `abadabad`? Can you confirm?

Comment: @silel Confirmed, that test case breaks my implementation, thanks for the heads up! It would only work if I change the while loop condition back to step < len(string) but that slows down the algo significantly.

Answer (score 0):

One line:

```
def remove_repeats(iterable):
    return [e for (i, e) in enumerate(iterable) if i == 0 or e != iterable[i - 1]]
```

It works with any iterable data, returns list.

```
>>> print remove_repeats("aaabbc")
['a', 'b', 'c']

>>> s = '''
... ul/li/a
... ul/li/div/div/div/a/span
... ul/li/div/div/div/a/span
... ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... ul/li/ul/li/a
... '''

>>> print remove_repeats(s.split())
['ul/li/a', 'ul/li/div/div/div/a/span', 'ul/li/a', 'ul/li/ul/li/a', 'ul/li/a', '
ul/li/ul/li/a', 'ul/li/a', 'ul/li/ul/li/a']
```

Join if you need a string:

```
>>> print "".join(remove_repeats('111222333'))
123

>>> print "\n".join(remove_repeats(s.split()))
ul/li/a
ul/li/div/div/div/a/span
ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
ul/li/a
ul/li/ul/li/a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
mystr = "dxabcabcyyyydxycxcxz"
index=0;indexs = [];count = OrderedDict()
while count!=None:
    count = {}
    for index in range(0,len(mystr)):
        flag = True
        for index1 in range(0,index+1)[::-1]:
            if(mystr.startswith(mystr[index1:index+1], index+1)):
                if count.get(str(index1),0)<(index+1-index1):
                    count.update({str(index1) : index+1-index1})
    for key in count:
        mystr = mystr[:int(key)]+mystr[int(key)+count[key]:]
    if count=={}:
        count=None
print "Answer:", mystr
```

Answer (score 0):

One linear approach

```
import itertools
_str = 'dxabcabcyyyydxycxcxz'
print ''.join(ch for ch, _ in itertools.groupby(_str))
```

result:

dxabcabcyyyydxycxcxz  -> dxabcabcydxycxcxz